# Can I use GoldenGate with Autonomous Database when source and target databases have different character sets?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

I want to use Goldengate to sync a source database with ATP. However, the character set in the source database is different than in ATP.

Is it possible to overcome the different character set between the source and target databases, and sync both databases correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The source and target databases having different character sets is automatically handled by Oracle GoldenGate when the target is an Oracle database. With Autonomous Database being on UTF8, the target character set is a superset of all source character sets. In other words, the source database can be synced with the target Autonomous database regardless of the source's character set.